# Newtonsoft.Json.Jobject.parse: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter position 32767

Tags: c#, json.net

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(strjson);
```

If  strjson is longer than 32767, it will have this error:

> Unterminated string. Expected delimiter position

I tried several strings, if it is not longer than 32767, works ok.
I guess it has something to do with my visual studio settings?

Comment: Json.NET itself can parse a string longer than 32767, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/dL4lKu for a demo.  So the problem is that `strjson` somehow got truncated, but there's no way for us to know how unless you share a [mcve] that demonstrates how it is constructed.  See also [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for tips on asking questions that are likely to be answerable.